# The search field for my html table does not show up anymore

Tags: html, jsp, search, html-table

I have code a table:

```
 <table data-widget="datatable" class="ibm-data-table ibm-altrows"" 
        data-tablerowselector="enable" data-info="true" data-paging="true" 
        data-searching="true" data-ordering="true"  data-widget="datatable" id="test1table">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Tags</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Description</th>    


                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
```

It should (and did at some time) come up with a table of information and a search field on top. 
The search field does not show up, although I selected data-searching="true". 
Has someone seen this behavior too? Are there additional conditions required for the search field?

Comment: There is no search field in your code. (There is one empty `<th></th>`, though where it may belong). What exactly is your question? Please note that questions on StackOverflow should be well defined, "Any idea why this doesn't work," does not count as one.

Comment: I updated the text, so now th etable part shows up